# Timepicker wrong returning of AM/PM android

Tags: android

I have a problem displaying the correct AM/PM of a calculated sleep cycle of a person. For example, the user clicks his waking time at 7:00 AM, the app should return the sleeping time at 11:15 PM. In my app, it's displaying 11:15 AM not PM.

Can you help me with what I have tried so far:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
             new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet( TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute ) {
            // Gets current time
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            // set waking time into textview
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(hour>=12){                      
              sb.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" PM");
            }else{
              sb.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" AM");
            }
            wakingtime.setText(sb);

            // Assign hour set in the picker
            c.set( Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour );
            c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute );

            // Have Calendar calculate the substraction of hours and minutes
            c.add( Calendar.HOUR, SUB_HOUR );
            c.add( Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_MINUTE );

            // Get the hour and the minute calculated
            hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR );
            minute = c.get( Calendar.MINUTE );

            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            if(hour>=12){                      
              sb2.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" PM");
            }else{
              sb2.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" AM");
            }
            answer.setText(sb2);

            // set current time into textview
            //answer.setText( "You must go to bed at " + new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                //  .append(":").append(pad(minute)) );


        }
    };
```

Any help is truly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line  if(hour>=12), run your code until you hit the breakpoint.  What value is hour?

Comment: @Simon, [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html) say it's the "hourOfDay". So this must be in 24 hour format.

Comment: Good point, so go ahead and answer.  hour = c.set(Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to the small discussion with @Simon above in the comments, the Calendar variable you want to set is Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) is what you're setting, and getting. You want the one that's below that.

Comment: So I will use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY?

Comment: Yes. Using the above code would make sense with Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY which is in the 24 hour format; The HOUR variable is in a 12 hour format.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for this question (im a newbie) where will I put Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY in my code?

Comment: Everywhere in the code you've posted, where you've used Calendar.HOUR replace it with Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY.
I hope you've written some part of this code because it would seem obvious, and I guess SO promotes efforts before resorting to this as a final resort. HTH anyway. :)

Comment: thanks buddy! It's working, now I understand that my variable hour is in 12 hr format. When I read the docs about HOUR_OF_DAY it gave me a clearer understanding of it. Thanks for pointing me to correct information. Therefore I will now accept your answer :)